# Base case not getting picked up in my F# function

Tags: f#

This function is supposed to just return the index of a list. That part works. However when a element is not in a list it must return -1.

For some reason it does not return -1.

```
let rec search f list =
    match list with
    | head::tail ->
           if f head then 0 
           else 1 + search f tail
    | [] -> -1



printfn "%A" (search (fun x -> x = 5) [ 5; 4; 3; 2 ])
//>> return index 0 for #5

printfn "%A" (search (fun x -> x = 6) [ 5; 4; 3; 2 ])
//>> should return -1 but it returns 3 which is the len of the list not -1
```

EDIT: Can not use nested functions.

Comment: because you add 1 each time you search,  so  1+1+1+1-1

Comment: ok how do I force the result to be -1?

Comment: well most trivial is make a wee function that takes the result of search f tail and returns a number +1 if >= 0 otherwise -1

Comment: Yeah but the trick here is do it in ONLY 1 function no nested functions, no intrinsic F# functions. Otherwise it be too easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use e.g.

```
let search f list =
  let rec where at list =
    match list with
    | [] -> -1
    | head::tail ->
        if f head then at
        else where (at + 1) tail
  where 0 list
```

which has the benefit of being tail-recursive. Regarding your comment:

```
let rec search f list =
  match list with
  | [] -> -1
  | head::tail ->
      if f head then 0 else
        match search f tail with
        | -1 -> -1
        | i -> i + 1
```

Comment: That's what I came up with. However I should have made it clear I can't do this with nested functions.

Comment: @boardkeystown I added a non-nested solution

Comment: Ohhhh I see it now. Wait so you can just search on the function as a list again!? That's awesome.